# Laravel 5 Join table and select Popular Category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have 2 tables, category and service

```
category_table
+----+--------------+
| id |   category   |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |  category_1  |
|  2 |  category_2  |
+----+--------------+

service_table
+----+--------------+-----------+
| id |    service   |   cat_id  |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |  service_a   |     1     |
|  2 |  service_b   |     1     |
|  3 |  service_c   |     1     |
|  4 |  service_d   |     2     |
+----+--------------+-----------+
```

I want to get the category count from the service table and display the result using the category name and limit it to 5 most used category
The desired result:

```
category name |  category count
  category_1  |         3
  category_2  |         1
```

Seems like i have to `join` or `leftjoin` these table, but it is pretty confusing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('category_table')
->leftJoin('service_table', 'category_table.id', '=', 'service_table.cat_id')
->select(DB::raw('category_table.category,count(service_table.cat_id) as category_count'))
->groupBy('service_table.cat_id')
->order_by('category_count', 'desc')
->take(5)
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you must use join's. You can rewrtie it with Eloquent, or use `DB::raw()` Try this:

```
SELECT c.category, COUNT(*) AS category_count FROM category_table c LEFT JOIN service_table s ON(c.id = s.cat_id) GROUP BY s.cat_id ORDER BY category_count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

P.S. I don't check it, but must work. [Good tutorial about joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)